# Selection of multiple json keys using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

As a newbee to bash and jq, I was trying to download several urls from a json file using jq command in bash scripts.

My items.json file looks like this :

```
［
   {"title" : [bob], "link" :[a.b.c]}, 
   {"title" : [alice], "link" :[d.e.f]}, 
   {"title" : [carol], "link" :[]} 
 ]
```

what I was initially doing was just filter the non-empty link and put them in an array and then download the array:

```
#!/bin/bash
lnk=( $(jq -r '.[].link[0] | select (.!=null)' items.json) )
for element in ${lnk[@]}
do
    wget $element
done
```

But the problem of this approach is that all the files downloaded use the link as the file names.

I wish to filter json file but still keeps the title name with the link so that i can rename the file in the wget command. But I dont have any idea on what structure should I use here. So how can i keep the title to in the filter and use it after?

Comment: The provided "items.json" file is not valid JSON. Please provide a valid input and an expected output sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a titles < <(jq -r '.[] | select (.link[0]!=null) | .title[0]' items.json);
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a links  < <(jq -r '.[] | select (.link[0]!=null) | .link[0]' items.json);
```

Then you can iterate over arrays `"${title[@]}"` & `${links[@]}`...

```
for i in ${!titles[@]}; do
    wget -O "${titles[i]}" "${links[@]}"
done
```

EDIT: Easier & safer approach:

```
jq -r '.[] | select (.link[0]!=null) | @sh "wget -O \(.title[0]) \(.link[0])"' items.json | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script demonstrating reading the result of a jq filter into bash variables.

```
#!/bin/bash
jq -M -r '
    .[] 
  | select(.link[0]!=null) 
  | .title[0], .link[0]
' items.json | \
while read -r title; read -r url; do
    echo "$title: $url" # replace with wget command
done
```